# How to change macro recording key binding in Sublime Text 3

Tags: macros, sublimetext3

Sublime Text's macro recording commands are binded to `ctrl+q`:

> To start recording a macro, press Ctrl+q and subsequently execute the
> desired steps one by one. When you’re done, press Ctrl+q again to stop
> the macro recorder.

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/macros.html#how-to-record-macros

Which also happens to be the `quit` command in Linux systems, the result being I can't record macros.

What are the `command` entries for macro recording (start/stop) in Sublimetext?

Comment: brito has the right answer, but just for the record the Unofficial docs don't mention that under Linux the default binding is actually `Ctrl+Alt+Q` to record the macro. Whatever the binding is currently set to is shown to you in the menu, which in this case is `Tools > Record Macro`.

Answer (score 1):

The macro-related key bindings can be found in https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html.

I have changed my `Key Bindings - User` settings to the following, which do not conflict with `quit` commands in Ubuntu:

```
[
    # ...
    { "keys": ["ctrl+m"], "command": "toggle_record_macro" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+m"], "command": "run_macro" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Sublime, the macro record/run is different and works in Linux.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+q"], "command": "toggle_record_macro" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+q"], "command": "run_macro" },
```